# Generators of the group of integers exercise

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.

(1) Prove that $\{a,b\}$ is a system of generators of $\mathbb Z$ if and only if $(a,b)=1$, where $(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor between $a$ and $b$.

(2)Show that $\mathbb Z$ has a system of minimal generators of $n$ elements for all $n$ in $\mathbb N$.

I suppose that saying $\{a,b\}$ is a system of generators of $\mathbb Z$ is equivalent to $<a> \cup <b>=\mathbb Z$. I am not so sure how to solve this exercise.

Suppose that the group is generated by those two elements, then any $z \in \mathbb Z$ can be written as $$z=as+bt, \space s,t \in \mathbb Z$$

How can I deduce from here that $(a,b)=1$?

I think I could do the other implication:

Suppose $(a,b)=1$, then $1$ can be written as a linear combination $$aq+br=1, \space, q,r \in \mathbb Z$$ Take an arbitrary integer $z$, then $$z=z(aq+br)=a(zq)+b(zr),$$ this means that $\{a,b\}$ generates $\mathbb Z$.

I would appreciate some help to prove the first implication and to show (2) I don't get the definition of "minimal generators system". Is my proof of the other implication correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\{a,b\}$ is a system of generators iff $<a,b>=\mathbb Z$. Here $<a,b>=\{na+mb\mid n,m\in\mathbb Z\}$. **Not** $<a>\cup<b>$ as you suppose.

Comment: For 1. think to Bezout's theorem.

Comment: If $(a,b) = d>1$, then $as+bt$ is divisible by $d$, so you cannot express all integers in this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** There exist $s, t$ such that $as+bt=\gcd(a, b)^{\dagger}$...so, what do you want the $\gcd$ to be?

You say you do not understand what a "minimal generating system" is. This is simply a set of elements $\{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}$ such that a proper subset will not generate your group.

**Hint 2:** Cycle primes. For example, $\{p_1p_2, p_2p_3, p_3p_1\}$ works for $n=3$. (Secondary hint: you will need to increase the lengths of your products as $n$ increases...)

$^{\dagger}$ This has a name: [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). Although I have only ever heard people call it by name on the internet...

Comment: I could show that if $\{a,b\}$ is a system of generators, then $(a,b)=1$, for this I've used the fact that $am+bn=1$ for some $m,n$ integers. I am still pretty lost with (2), I've understood the definition of minimal generating system.

Comment: Further hint: the following works for $n=4$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes.$$\{p_1p_2p_3, p_2p_3p_4, p_3p_4p_1, p_4p_1p_2\}$$

Comment: Ok, I got your idea, I choose $n$ distinct primes, and I define $\{\{a_1,...,a_j\} : a_j=\prod_{1\leq i \leq n, i \neq j}p_i\}$. I am not so sure how to show it generates $\mathbb Z$ and that it is minimal generating system.

Comment: @user what is the gcd of the whole set?

Comment: $1$, now I got it, I didn't know Bezout could be extended to more than two integers.

Comment: @user It can, but it is not obvious! You may want to try and prove it properly yourself, by inducting on the number of integers.